# Docusign List Batch

Tags: docusignapi

What is the correct method for listing Batches? I used this method and it returns null.

```
public IEnumerable<BulkSendBatchSummary> ListBatchs(int numberOfItems)    
    {
        var accessToken = docuSignClient.getTokenAccess(integratorKey, userId, authServer, basePath);
        var apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
        apiClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        var bulkEnvelopesApi = new BulkEnvelopesApi(apiClient);
        
        var option = new BulkEnvelopesApi.GetBulkSendBatchesOptions
        {             
            status = "all",
            count = numberOfItems.ToString(),
            

        };
     IEnumerable<BulkSendBatchSummary> listeBatchs = bulkEnvelopesApi.GetBulkSendBatches(accountId, option).BulkBatchSummaries;
       
    return listeBatchs;
    }
```

Comment: It's possible there's a bug in either documentation or this API endpoint. I cannot check this until after the holidays. I'll get back to you then.

Comment: thank you ! , no problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct C# code :

```
var apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
apiClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
var bulkEnvelopesApi = new BulkEnvelopesApi(apiClient);
bulkEnvelopesApi.GetBulkSendBatches(accountId);
```